# How do I connect N circles of the same diameter tangentially?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

If I have N number of circles all with the same diameter, how do I determine the minimum inscribed polygon that will connect them tangentially? Is there a formula to do this?

Once that polygon is created, I *believe* a circle will be placed at the midpoint of each line segment.

A few examples of what I'm going for in pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdr4U.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

Place  circle centers at positions relative common center:

[image]

```
R = r / Sin(Pi/N)

coordinates for i-th circle center:

cx(i) = R * Cos(i * 2 * Pi / N)
cy(i) = R * Sin(i * 2 * Pi / N)
```

where N is number of circles, r is circle radius